# disable "Quickfix list" in Syntastic

Tags: vim, syntastic

I'm happily using the [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) plugin for vim. The "Quickfix list" at the bottom of the window (technically, it's another vim window) takes up space and I don't really use it. Disabling the quickfix list via

```
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 0                                    
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 0
```

in `~/.vimrc` does not work.
What options need to be set for disabling the quickfix list?

Comment: `let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 0` is the one you need and it works perfectly, could you show us your `~/.vimrc`?

Comment: @romainl that worked for me.

Comment: @romainl I have a problem with this wickfix list, because it opens on false positive ... Indeed I write a report in french and I always have the warning : Whitespace before punctation mark in " !"
And this warning opens a quickfix window because of Syntastic.
Is there a way to know from which plugin this warning comes from ? So I could be able to disable it, or precise the language to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an MWE takes some time, but almost always helps identifying the error. In this case, two packages did the syntax checking, namely

```
Bundle 'scrooloose/syntastic'                                                   
Bundle 'andviro/flake8-vim'
```

It was `flake8-vim` that introduced the quickfix list. Disabling it obviously fixes the problem.

Comment: What is a MWE @Nico Schlömer ?